# StartExec vpn systemd

Tags: systemd, vpn

I want to create systemd unit nordvpnconnect.service to autoconnect my vpn after boot. Nordvpnd daemon starts first, and I have my unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=NordVPN connector 
After=nordvpnd.service nordvpnd.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nordvpn connect Estonia
NonBlocking=true
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=default.targe
```

It doesn't work, and when cchecking `journalctl -u nordvpnconnect -f` I see:

```
Started NordVPN connector.
lis 09 01:01:56 maciexhome nordvpn[7872]: [38B blob data]
lis 09 01:01:56 maciexhome nordvpn[7872]: Stdin/Stdout should be terminal
lis 09 01:01:56 maciexhome systemd[1]: nordvpnconnect.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
lis 09 01:01:56 maciexhome systemd[1]: nordvpnconnect.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nordvpn c 'Estonia'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/'nordvpn c Estonia'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/"nordvpn c Estonia"
```

There were different logs in journal, but nothing works. Could someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on [their support page](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1047409422/How-can-I-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Terminal.htm), you should just use `openvpn` not any sort of `nordvpn` command. And I would be strongly surprised with any construct of this type: `/usr/bin/"nordvpn c Estonia"`, as it means the command name in `/usr/bin` would be `nordvpn c Estonia`, which is very, very non-standard. They rather just give you their certificate and let you use it with your `openvpn`. Here's an example from their site:

```
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/us2957.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn
```

Comment: I will try, thanks. The point is, why my command doesn't work via systemd unit. When you use this command in terminal, it works properly. It connects and run without problem. So I don't understand what is wrong with my systemd unit.